# Edit hover label text in ggplot to show percentage

Tags: r, ggplot2, tooltip, r-plotly

I'm trying to update the hover labels in my plot to show "Percentage: XX%" (where XX is the value of the percentage of each bar).

Here is some reproducible code:

```
## Data from https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/People/Indicators-of-quality-of-life-and-city-services-by/e6er-4cb3

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
data <- read.csv("Indicators_of_quality_of_life_and_city_services_by_year.csv")
head(data)
#data$Indicator.Theme
#data$Type
data <- data[,c("Indicator.Theme", "Type")]
data

que_code <- data %>% mutate(newcat = Indicator.Theme)
response <- que_code$newcat
category <- factor(que_code$Type)
textfill= "Type"

plott <- ggplot(que_code, aes(x=response, fill=category)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", width = 0.5, aes(y = (..count..)*100/sum(..count..), label="Percentage")) + labs(fill= textfill) + xlab("Response to survey questions")+ylab("Percentage")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ae3cc6", "#9630a8", "#842791", "#6d1b73", "#780e55",
                               "#7e0643", "#820036", "#a11635", "#bb2835", "#d93d35",
                               "#e74735", "#fd5634", "#fe7c5b", "#ffa182"), drop=FALSE) + scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 30))

plott <- ggplotly(plott, tooltip="y")
```

What my plot looks like

[image]

I would like to change the variable name in the hover label from `(..count..)*100/sum(..count..)` to "Percentage".

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been struggling with this for a while ahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to pre-calculate the values to plot instead of using `(..count..)*100/sum(..count..)`. This would also need to change `geom_bar` to `geom_col`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

plott <- que_code %>%
  count(Type, Indicator.Theme, name = 'Percentage') %>%
  mutate(Percentage = prop.table(Percentage) * 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Indicator.Theme, fill=Type)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge", width = 0.5, aes(y = Percentage)) + 
  labs(fill= textfill) + 
  xlab("Response to survey questions")+
  ylab("Percentage") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ae3cc6", "#9630a8", "#842791", "#6d1b73", "#780e55",
                               "#7e0643", "#820036", "#a11635", "#bb2835", "#d93d35",
                               "#e74735", "#fd5634", "#fe7c5b", "#ffa182"), drop=FALSE) + 
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 30))

plott <- ggplotly(plott, tooltip="y")
plott
```

[image]